# Python 3.2 dealing with Redirect to relative url HTTP Error 302

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.2

I am trying to enter a website with Python 3.2 using no extra modules.

I am using urllib.request.urlopen(site), but when you request the site it throws an HTTP 302 Error due to an unhandled PHP redirect to "/"

During the redirect the website sets a cookie which is needed to further access the site.

How would I handle this in Python?

Comment: Have a look at the docs for http.cookiejar for the cookie stuff: http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/http.cookiejar.html#examples . And HTTPRedirectHandler for redirects: http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/library/urllib.request.html#httpredirecthandler-objects

Comment: Sorry, but for the past couple of days I have been unable to even go to http://www.python.org/ I'm pretty sure that it's down for maintenance or something =\

Comment: It's been up and down a bit. It seems to be up at the moment, though.

Comment: After reading up on the docs for Python 3.2.1 I still do not know what I am supposed to do to handle the redirect to the main site.
Sorry I'm a bit new to Python, just transferred from VB.net

Comment: I'm not quite sure - the docs suggest it handles 302 redirects by default. You might want to post a new question with tracebacks and code.

Comment: I know you said no external modules, but if you can, I highly recommend [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

A 302 redirect isn't quite "200 success", but I wouldn't quite call it an error, either, not until you GET the url it directs you to. The website may have internal errors, but the response is a straightforward redirect and that's what your client code cares about.

In python3.2 it often made sense to try to stick to "batteries included" and rely on standard libraries like urllib.

At this point, you should definitely use requests. See for example this [standard documentation example](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#cookies):

```
>>> r = requests.get(url)
>>> r.cookies['example_cookie_name']
```